# Return first element from relation with `Lazy Eager Loading` [Laravel 5.2]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have relation like this:

```
public function message()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Engine\Message');
}
```

inside my `Conversation` model.

and for each conversation I need to get last message.

Here is what I tried, but this will get only one message for first conversation but will not get message from other conversations...

```
$con = Conversation::all();

$con->load(['message' => function ($q) use ( &$mess ) {
                $mess = $q->first();
            }]);

return $con;
```

I don't wana query for each record... Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This blog post is your answer: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Comment: add ->take(1). It will return an array/collection of related models that contains 1 item only

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/first-and-take-do-not-work-correctly-in-eager-load-laravel?page=0)!

Don't use `first()` or `get()` in eager loadings you should create a new relationship in the model.

The model would look something like this...

```
public function message()

{

    return $this->hasOne('Engine\Message');

}
```

kudos to 'pmall'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$con = Conversation::all();
$con->load(['message' => function ($q) use ( &$mess ) {
                $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1);
                // or if you don't use timestamps
                // $q->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)
            }]);
return $con;
```

Comment: Thanks for try but not working... In one conversation it get 1 message but  in others just blank...