# How can i convert this sql query in a eloquent laravel command?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in sql query this commando do exactly i wanted:

```
SELECT 
    v.id,
    ( 
        SELECT sv.status_id 
        FROM status_viagem sv 
        WHERE sv.viagem_id = v.id 
        ORDER BY sv.created_at DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS status_id
FROM viagens v
```

Here is the sql results:

[image]

But i have no idea how can i do this using Laravel eloquent

**Basically, a viagem entry can has a lot of status, but i need to get each viagem and their last status entry from status_viagem table (the pivot table)**

*by the way viagem/viagens means travel.*

My class mapping:

```
class Viagem extends Model
{
  ...
  public function status()
  {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withTimestamps();
  }
  ...
}


class Status extends Model
{

    public function viagens()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Viagem')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

The belongsToMany at both classes gets me a many-to-many:

[image: many-to-many]

can someone help me? thanks

---------- **Temporary Solution** -------

Thanks for all help  guys. In fact i can't find a nice solution using only eloquent.

Step 1/3 - To bypass this situation i first execute the above sql to grab only the viagens under the desired status_id (last status_viagem entry):

```php
$viagens_ids = DB::select(
            "SELECT viagem_id FROM (
                SELECT 
                    v.id AS viagem_id,
                    ( 
                        SELECT sv.status_id 
                        FROM status_viagem sv 
                        WHERE sv.viagem_id = v.id 
                        ORDER BY sv.id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS status_id
                FROM viagens v
            ) AS tt

            WHERE tt.status_id = {$status->id}"
        );
```

Step 2/3 - then i used the array_map to organize my viagens ids

```php
$a = array_map(
                function($obj) { return $obj->viagem_id; }, 
                $viagens_ids
            );
```

Step 3/3 - And at last i used elequent whereIn to fetch my viagens:

```php
 Viagem::with( 'status')->whereIn('id', $a)->get();
```

In fact i have solved the problem by a-old-sashion-way but i not happy with it because i wish i learn how to do it using eloquent. what bad to me.

Comment: hi Jonathan, have you tried constrained eager loading? something like `Viagem::with('status', function($query){ return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();  }`. you can use `toSql` to see the resulting sql query.

Comment: hi @bagus we are almost there. I use this command:
```
$viagens = Viagem::with(['status' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        }])->get();
``` but it does not work like the sql comman and shows wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to query in laravel. I have created a [test project](https://bitbucket.org/BagusTesa/sto-answers/src/4358ed4a9b884afdd8da503af70e97cdb39dc79b/?at=answer%2F60271510) for you to try. The gist are:

## 1. Eloquent ORM

Eloquent ORM is Laravel's magic which have [some limitations in eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56046030/4648586) - which i just come across while contemplating your question for hours. It wont play nicely with `first()`, `last()`, and some more functions in the constrained eager loading closure.

In your case, our almost there can be fixed:

```
   App\Models\Viagem::with(['status' => function($query){
          return $query->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc');
         }])
        ->get()
```

It will return entire field for `Viagem` and `Status` including its pivot table (the `status_viagem`).

However, if you wanted to retrieve only `viagem.id` and `status_viagem.status_id`, you can [`map()`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/Enumerable.html#method_map) it as such:

```
   App\Models\Viagem::with(['status' => function($query){
           return $query->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc');
         }])
        ->get()
        ->map(function($data){
           $o = new stdClass();
           $o->id = $data->id;
           $o->status_id = $data->status->first()->id;
           return $o;
        });
```

Please take note that the statement above require sql query to be ran twice. Eager loading basically works by querying all the `Viagem` first then queries the `Status` and map them in memory based on the foreign keys. You can observe that replacing `get` with `toSql` will only give you the first query. Please enable [Query Logging](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging) to see the second query.

## 2. Query Builder

Embarking from [Ryan Adhitama Putra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12883692/ryan-adhitama-putra) answer, you could do something like:

```
   App\Models\Viagem::join('status_viagem', 'viagens.id', '=', 'status_viagem.viagem_id')
       ->orderBy('status_viagem.created_at', 'desc')
       ->groupBy(['status_viagem.status_id', 'viagens.id'])
       ->select(['viagens.id', 'status_viagem.status_id'])
       ->get();
```

This query builder approach guaranteed to be ran only once, you can replace the `get()` with `toSql()` to see the resulting query.

## 3. Raw Queries

Throwing `DB::raw()` can help sometime, but i really did not want to mention it.

Comment: thank you @Bagus for your amazing answer. I going to set it as best answer. I added a new section at the question (Temporary Solution). see you .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what viagens and viagem represent, but I think one of the relationships has to be belongsToMany() and the other hasMany().

then after you set relationships correctly, you can use Eloquent like this :

```
$status_id = Viagem::with('status')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->pluck('status_id');
```

Comment: Hi @Siba, it is a many-to-many, like says the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) with a reverse mapping.

Comment: @JhonatanMorais did you try the query above? I think It should work.

Comment: Hi @Siba, but it did not work, here is the result: *SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERRO: column "status_id" does not exists LINE 1: select "status_id" from "viagens" ^ (SQL: select "status_id" from "viagens")* I had improve the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$status_id = Viagem::join('status','viagem.id','status_viagem.viagem_id')
             ->select('viagem.id','status_viagem.status_id')
             ->get();
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan, you suggestion didn't work too: here is the results:
*SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERRO: missing entry to table "viagem" at statement  FROM LINE 1: ..."status_id" from "viagens" inner join "status" on "viagem"."... ^ (SQL: select "viagem"."id", "status_viagem"."status_id" from "viagens" inner join "status" on "viagem"."id" = "status_viagem"."viagem_id")*